# Display CPT index page as front/home page

Tags: custom-post-types, archives

I'm building a website that's sole purpose is to display other websites (defined in the CPT). Think of it as a portfolio site for a company's digital assets. I have already defined the CPT and added websites to it. I created a `portfolio-archive.php` template (the CPT's name). Which is now accessed at the `/portfolio` slug. I want this to be the homepage of the site. How would I go about doing  that?

Comment: If the portfolio slug is a page, you can set that as your homepage under settings > reading, otherwise you can just do it at the domain or server level.

Comment: It's not a page, it's the archive page of a custom post type. I tried the settings>reading option, not helping. As far as a sever thing, I'm using WP Engine, what should I ask them? @AndrewBartel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `portfolio-archive.php` to `front-page.php` and change the post type for that page with a filter on `pre_get_posts`:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_99860_portfolio_on_front' );

function wpse_99860_portfolio_on_front( $query )
{
    // not the main loop
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return $query;

    // not the front page
    if ( ! $query->is_front_page() )
        return $query;

    $query->set( 'post_type', array ( 'portfolio' ) );

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: What if this theme is genesis theme? Would that make a difference? @toscho

Comment: It shouldn’t. There is no "r" in my name …

Comment: I was having FTP issues, I was finally able to make the changes. It seems to have worked minus keeping the correct styles. Any idea why? @toscho

Comment: The output from `body_class()` is different on the front page. You might have to adjust the stylesheet.

Comment: you're the best!